# SAS - Grouping by ID, how do I convert all values to the minimum value of 1 of the rows?

Tags: sas

I want an data-step or SQL statement to do the following.

Consider this table:

(Before)

```
id  div dlenfol repurch rlenfol
1   0   145      1         25
2   0   114      0         114
2   0   114      0         114
3   0   189      1         53
3   0   189      0         189
3   1   149      0         189
4   1   14       0         182
4   0   182      1         46
4   0   182      0         182
```

Grouping by id, how do I convert all the values of dlenfol to the minimum value in the dlenfol column, and all the values of rlenfol to the minimum value in the rlenfol column?

Meanwhile I also want to create a variable called choice that:

```
=1 if a certain id EVER had a div=1; 
=0 if a certain id EVER had a repurch=1 (but never had a div=1); 
=1 if a certain id EVER had a div=1 AND EVER had a repurch=1; 
and =. if the certain id never had a div=1 nor repurch=1.
```

i.e. Like this:

(After)

```
id  div dlenfol repurch rlenfol choice
1   0   145        1    25         0
2   0   114        0    114        .
2   0   114        0    114        .
3   0   149        1    53         1
3   0   149        0    53         1
3   1   149        0    53         1
4   1   14         0    46         1
4   0   14         1    46         1
4   0   14         0    46         1
```

The code I've been trying is not working:

```
data comb2d;
set comb;
do;
    set comb;
    by id;
    dmin = min(dlenfol, dmin);
    rmin = min(rlenfol, rmin);
    if dlenfol=dmin and rlenfol^=rmin then CHOICE=1;
    else if dlenfol^=dmin and rlenfol=rmin then CHOICE=0;
    else if dlenfol=dmin and rlenfol=rmin then CHOICE=1;
    else CHOICE=.;
    /* if DIV=1 and REPURCH=0 then CHOICE=1;
    else if DIV=0 and REPURCH=1 then CHOICE=0;
    else if DIV=1 and REPURCH=1 then CHOICE=1;
    else CHOICE=.; */
  end;
  dlenfol = dmin;
  rlenfol = rmin;
  /* drop dmin;
  drop rmin; */
run;
```

The following SQL code seems to solve the minimum value issue but it creates 2 variables (dmin and rmin) that I don't really need:

```
proc sql;
create table comb3 as
select *, min(dlenfol) as dmin, min(rlenfol) as rmin
from comb
group by comb.id;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc sort data=before out=sort1;
by id dlenfol;
run;

data sort1;
   drop temp;
set sort1;
retain temp;
   by id;
      if first.id then temp = dlenfol;
      else dlenfol = temp;
run;

then do the same thing for rlenfol
```

Comment: Hi DCR.  Thanks for your answer but it results in missing values for most of the dlenfol entries.  Remember that I need to convert all the values of dlenfol to the minimum value in the dlenfol column.  Also, do you have any ideas about how to create the Choice variable?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry about that, we need to add the retain statement

Comment: I just came up with some SQL code but it creates 2 new variables (dmin and rmin) that I don't really need:                                                        proc sql;
create table comb3 as
select *, min(dlenfol) as dmin, min(rlenfol) as rmin
from comb
group by comb.gvkey;
quit;

Comment: are you using compustat data?

Comment: Yes, compustat data.  Sorry I meant to type "id" instead of "gvkey"

Comment: It's unfortunately getting rows out of original sequence.  I have rows sorted within each id (gvkey) by a year variable.  The sorting is changing that.  The proc sql code seems to work without affecting the sort order, however, so I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the extra 2 variables (dmin and rmin) in that.  Also, my choice variable is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
proc sql;
create table comb3 as
select id,  div , repurch , min(dlenfol) as dlenfol, min(rlenfol) as relenfol
from comb
group by comb.id;
quit;
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work and it also strangely suffers from the sorting issue.  The following works better (and I've decided I'll just have to keep the extra 2 variables (dmin and rmin), but the Choice variable code is still not working:  'proc sql;
create table comb3 as
select *, min(dlenfol) as dmin, min(rlenfol) as rmin, max(choice) as choice
from comb
group by comb.gvkey;
order by comb.gvkey, comb.fyear;
quit;'

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be working now:

```
proc sql;
create table comb3 as
select *, min(dlenfol) as dmin, min(rlenfol) as rmin, max(choice) as choicemax
from comb
group by comb.gvkey
order by comb.gvkey, comb.fyear;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of a problem that can be handled by a double DOW loop. In the first loop find the minimums and check if the flag variables are ever true.
You then have the information needed to define the new CHOICE variable and set the variables to their minimum.

```
data want ;
  do until(last.id);
    set have ;
    by id ;
    mind=min(mind,dlenfol);
    minr=min(minr,rlenfol);
    anydiv=anydiv or div;
    anyrep=anyrep or repurch;
  end;
  if anydiv then choice=1;
  else if anyrep then choice=0;
  else choice=.;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    dlenfol=mind;
    rlenfol=minr;
    output;
  end;
  drop mind minr anydiv anyrep;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom.  Thanks for your answer.  My proc sql code above seems to be working ok but I appreciate your solution too.  Can I ask you a slightly different question?  It turns out I need to have Choice=1 if Div=1 in a year prior to Repurch being =1 (if, for a certain id, both Div=1 and Repurch=1 at some point).  Similarly, I must have Choice=0 if Repurch=1 in a year prior to Div being =1.  Do you have any advice on how to do that?